# Selenium -Java runtime error

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have written a test case and don't see any compilation errors but when I run the test case the browser opens and it suddenly gets closed within a second by  throwing this error:

```
**Starting ChromeDriver 2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129) on port 7788
Only local connections are allowed.
Sep 29, 2016 1:37:50 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.ProcessUtils killWinProcess
WARNING: Process refused to die after 10 seconds, and couldn't taskkill it
java.lang.RuntimeException: exec return code 1: ERROR: The parameter is incorrect.**
```

**I'm using 32-bit OS vista**
I have tried

```
System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.driver", "Chrome.driver.exe");`
System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.driver", "Chromedriver.exe");
System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.driver", "C : \\desktop\\Chrome.driver.exe");
```

but still throwing the same error

Comment: Could you provide entire stacktrace?

Comment: yes,its properly provided

Comment: does this issue is relate to my OS ?

Comment: What version of selenium and chrome are you using as well??

Comment: please update this `System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.driver","path to chromedriver");`

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in your third line:
the path should be to **Chromedriver.exe** and not **chrome.driver.exe**

Also you don't need to include the 1st two lines, just use:

```
System.setProperty("WebDriver.Chrome.driver", "C : \\desktop\\Chromedriver.exe");
```

Just check if Chromedriver starts with capital C or not.

Hope it helps, cheers.

Comment: ,FYI - This is not case sensitive , either small 'c' or Capital 'C' works fine.